# Alignment problem with the \question command

Tags: spacing, enumerate, exam, text

I am currently typing a document in latex using the "\question" command and noticed that the question numbers do not lie all the way to the far left of the page, with some indent. In the attached image, there is a rounded box which goes up to the left margin, and there is clearly some space between the edge of the box and where the number "1." begins. I tried to use the "\flushleft" command but this did not work. Any help on getting the numbers in line with the box would be great.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{26cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2 truecm}
\setlength{\parindent}{2cm} 
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question questions
\begin{parts}
\part[2] part one
\part[4] part two
\part[4] part three
\end{parts}
\begin{solution}[10cm]
 solution
\end{solution} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you provide a full code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The code is just \begin{questions}
\question questions

\begin{parts}
\part[2] part one
\part[4] part two
\part[4] part three
\end{parts}
\begin{solution}[10cm]
solution
\end{solution} with the relevant packages installed.

Comment: That isn't a full code. Which packages? Which document class?

Comment: Here's a list of the pacakages, document class and other page properties, the only thing not in the list is the code for the box but I doubt that is making any difference. \documentclass[11pt, A4paper]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\textheight}{26cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm} \setlength{\parskip}{0.2 truecm}
\setlength{\parindent}{2cm}

Comment: Er wordt natuurlijk genoeg ruimte gereserveerd voor het nummer zodat ook grotere nummers nog passen.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Comments are the wrong place for code blocks, it's better to edit the question. I added the code you've posted to your post, changing `A4paper` to `a4paper`, adding `\begin{document}` and `\end{questions}\end{document}`.

Comment: the code provided doesn't produce the box.  however, i suspect that the alignment of the question numbers has been set so that if more than one digit is required to number the questions, the decimal points following the question numbers will align, and the indentation of the question text and parts will be uniform.

Answer (score 2):

The questions environment is a list and its label is set right aligned. You can redefine it:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{exam}
\begin{document}
xxxxx\\
xxxx

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil}%
}
\begin{questions}
\question questions
\begin{parts}
\part[2] part one
\part[4] part two
\part[4] part three
\end{parts}
\begin{solution}[10cm]
 solution
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]